# Difference between single quotes and double quotes in java?

Tags: java

I have

1. `System.out.println(2+" "+3);`
2. `System.out.println(2+' '+3);`

The first one prints 2 3 while the second prints 37 Can any of guys explain why it is printing 37???

Comment: Using single quotes is for characters and double quotes is for strings.  When you add a character it is a number, When you add a string it appends a String.

Comment: char and int are different views on a value.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Java Language Specification for [Additive Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.18):

> If the type of either operand of a `+` operator is `String`, then the operation is string concatenation.
>
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the `+` operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type

[For Numeric Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.18.2):

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2)

[Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/conversions.html#170983):

> [...] Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

So, `2+" "+3` is `2 + " "`, which is a string concatenation, and `String + 3` is also a string concatenation, hence `2 + " " + 3` is `"2" + " " + "3"` which means `"2 3"`.

`2+' '+3` is `2 + ' '`, and the space literal is a `char`, so it is converted to `int` (32), and `2 + 32 + 3` is `37`.

---

If the literals had been variables, it would actually be like this, where the assignment to a variable is only used to illustrate the type of the intermediate result:

```
// String concatenation
String s = new StringBuilder().append(2).append(" ").append(3).toString();
System.out.println(s);

// Numeric addition
int n = 2 + (int)' ' + 3;
System.out.println(n);
```

Both `append()` and `println()` are overloaded, so they are not all the same method.

Since they are literals, and not variables, the compiler will do it at compile-time, and you really get this (try disassembling a .class file to see for yourself):

```
System.out.println("2 3");
System.out.println(37);
```

Answer (score 3):

`' '= 32` in ascii .

```
a:) System.out.println(2+" "+3); // string concatenation

b:) System.out.println(2+' '+3);  // 2+ 32(32 ascii valur for space)+3 so 37
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is converting everything to string for you.  The second one is converting to integer.  The decimal code for space is 32.  If you want 2 and 3 to be string then use the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are printing the integer values of `2+ ' ' +3` and it will translate `' '` it as a `char` not a `string` which simply converts the b) part to it's ASCII values which result into `2 + ASCII value of Space + 3` and the final result would be 37 as the ASCII value of a `space` is 32.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is performing string concatenation, so the answer is pretty intuitive. The second example is different because ' ' is not a string, it's a char. The char is converted to an integer code, which is why you're getting that number.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation like here is almost one situation where Java is so tolerant. In other context with char ' ' and String " " shows true: there are strong different types.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the output argument for `System.out.println` is explicitly a `java.lang.String` java will automatically convert whatever datatypes and objects it is given as output arguments to `java.lang.String`.

In your first example, `System.out.println(2+" "+3);` what java does is scan through the output arguments and finds an `int` (2), the double quotes `" "` which indicates the array of characters inside the double quotes are to be interpreted as a `String`, and another `int` (3). Java takes the presence  of the String `" "` as a hint that everything else in the argument should be treated as Strings as well. So what effectively happens is that the line `System.out.println(2+" "+3);` is treated as if you had written

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(2)+" "+Integer.toString(3));
```

In your second example, `System.out.println(2+' '+3);` the same process occurs, but rather than finding the double quotes, java finds `' '` --  a whitespace surrounded by single quotes, which tells java that it is working with the primitive data type `char` -- and here's why java treats this as an addition operation: [all java primitive data types are numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) -- so java takes that hint and interprets the output arguments as an `int`(2), the addition operator(+), a `char`(a whitespace character) -- which is the same as an unsigned `short`,  the addition operator(+), and another `int`(3). The numeric value of the whitespace character is 32, so the behind the scenes conversion treats your statement like you had written

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(2+32+3));
```

Of course, the parsing that goes on behind the scenes is even more complicated than I could describe for you here. Why don't you try:

```
    System.out.println("The answer is "+(3+" "+2));
    System.out.println("The answer is "+(3+2));
    System.out.println("The answer is "+(3+' '+2));
```

or even

```
System.out.println('a' + 'b' + 'c');
```

Comment: Actually, the first println is `System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(2).append(" ").append(3).toString());` and the second is `System.out.println( 2 + (int)' ' + 3 );`, though in reality the compiler will do it at compile-time.

Comment: "all java primitive data types are numbers", except for boolean.

Comment: @Andreas, well then pray tell, why don't you explain for the class how the JVM DOES treat a boolean?

Comment: Sure: `2 + true` and `true + 2` is compile error. `"x" + true` and `true + "x"` is string concatenation after converting the boolean to string.

Comment: then how is the boolean stored and compared by the JVM?

Comment: A boolean is stored as a value that is either true or false. It's physically stored as a bit, the same way everything else is stored as one or more bits.

Comment: "it's physically stored as a bit, the same way everything else is stored as one or more bits" That's a less clever way to avoid answering the question than you might think. And a bit is a 1 or a 0, yes? And ones and zeroes are what, again?

Comment: That is an exact and direct answer. A bit is not a number, although it's always represented as 0 or 1. The string "Hello" is stored as 5 * 16 = 80 bits, but is in no ways considered a number. Sure, a lot of other languages allow assigning/casting boolean values to a number, where you get 0 for false and 1 for true. Java is *not* one of those languages.

Comment: Flag my answer then Andreas. If this tedious nitpicking is that important to you, flag it.

Comment: It's not important to me. I was being helpful in pointing out that your statement was not entirely correct. Normally, a poster would have added the extra "except for boolean" to their answer, and that would have been it. I'd likely have deleted the comment then. You can still do that, and I'll delete all my comments except the first. Whether you apply that too or let your answer stand is entirely up to you.